# Equivalent of backreferences in a g command?

Tags: global-command

I'm formatting a multiple-choice quiz to be imported into an LMS.  The questions are currently formatted like this, with the asterisk indicating the correct solution:

```
1. Question text
a. First answer
*b. Second answer
c. Third answer
d. Fourth answer
```

And I need to change the format to:

```
1. Question text
a. First answer
b. Second answer
c. Third answer
d. Fourth answer
Answer: b
```

One option is `:g/^\*b\./norm x}OAnswer: b`, but then I need run similar commands for a, c, and d to make sure I captured all the answers.  It would be great if I could use backreferences, like `:g/^\*\([a-d]\)\./norm x}OAnswer: \1` but I know backreferences won't work.  I thought of yanking the correct answer's letter, }-ing down, and pasting it, but I'm drawing a blank as to how to write the commands to accomplish that.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It would be great if I could use backreferences, like `:g/^\*\([a-d]\)\./norm x}OAnswer: \1` but I know backreferences won't work. I thought of yanking the correct answer's letter, }-ing down, and pasting it, but I'm drawing a blank as to how to write the commands to accomplish that. Any ideas?

```
:g/^\*[a-d]\./norm! xyl}OAnswer: ^[p
```

Where `^[` is typed as `<c-v><esc>` (or `<c-q><esc>` depending on your config).

Comment: It seems to assumes that there is a blank line after the paragraph.

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt Yes, just like in the OP. Might be wrong for the last para, of course, but, imo, that's a very minor problem.

Comment: This is great -- I thought another solution might be something like this, but forgot about switching from insert to normal mode in a :g command.  Sorry to be dense, but what does the grouping do here?  I see the \( and \) but no \1

Comment: @Blair Well, actually nothing. That was due to copy-paste.

Answer (score 2):

This one assumes that the "blocks" are all followed by at least one empty line:

```
:g/^\*/s/^\*//|t/^$/-|s/^\(.\).*/Answer: \1
```

- The `:help :g` command matches lines that start with `*`.
- The first `:help :s` command removes the leading `*`.
- The `:help :t` command copies the current line to after the last choice line.
- The second `:s` command prepends `Answer:`  to the letter and gets rid of what comes after it.

Using only Ex commands for fun and profit.

Comment: You might be able to use `:t '}` or similar instead of `:t /^$/-`

Answer (score 1):

I would do:

```
:%s/\v^\*(.)(%(.+\n)+)/\1\2Answer: \1/
```

Where:

- `\v` turn super magic on (to avoid to have to escape the special signs)
- `^\*` match the start of the line that starts with `*` (the super magic force you to escape the special sign when they are meant to match literally)
- `%(.+\n)` match a line (but not create a group that can be referenced)
- `(%(.%\n)+)` match the rest of the paragraph (excluding blank line)